# Understanding Lambda Expressions

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm not quite sure I understand the Lambda Expressions tutorial within the Oracle Java tutorials. The main thing that confuses me is the Index parameter of the lambda.`ds.print(index ->{...}`  How does the compiler know what value index even is? Index isn't declared anywhere else in the program so what exactly is the Index parameter even referencing and how is the compiler able to know?

Excerise in question:

```
public class DataStructure {

    private final static int SIZE = 15;
    private int[] arrayOfInts = new int[SIZE];

    public DataStructure() {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            arrayOfInts[i] = i;
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        return SIZE;
    }

    public int get(int index) {
        return arrayOfInts[index];
    }

    interface DataStructureIterator extends java.util.Iterator<Integer> { }

    private class EvenIterator implements DataStructureIterator {

        private int nextIndex = 0;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return (nextIndex <= SIZE - 1);
        }

        public Integer next() {
            Integer retValue = Integer.valueOf(arrayOfInts[nextIndex]);
            nextIndex += 2;
            return retValue;
        }
    }

    public DataStructureIterator getEvenIterator() {
        return new EvenIterator();
    }

    public void printEven() {
        DataStructureIterator iterator = getEvenIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void print(DataStructureIterator iterator) {
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void print(java.util.function.Function<Integer, Boolean> function) {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            if (function.apply(i)) {
                System.out.print(arrayOfInts[i] + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static Boolean isEvenIndex(Integer index) {
        if (index % 2 == 0) return Boolean.TRUE;
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }

    public static Boolean isOddIndex(Integer index) {
        if (index % 2 == 0) return Boolean.FALSE;
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {

        DataStructure ds = new DataStructure();

        System.out.println("printEven()");
        ds.printEven();

        System.out.println("print(DataStructureIterator) with "
                + "getEvenIterator");
        ds.print(ds.getEvenIterator());

        System.out.println("print(DataStructureIterator) with "
                + "anonymous class, odd indicies");
        ds.print(
                new DataStructure.DataStructureIterator() {
                    private int nextIndex = 1;
                    public boolean hasNext() {
                        return (nextIndex <= ds.size() - 1);
                    }
                    public Integer next() {
                        int retValue = ds.get(nextIndex);
                        nextIndex += 2;
                        return retValue;
                    }
                }
        );

        System.out.println("print(Function) with lambda expressions");
        ds.print(index -> {
            if (index % 2 == 0) return Boolean.TRUE;
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        });
        ds.print(index -> {
            if (index % 2 == 0) return Boolean.FALSE;
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        });

        System.out.println("print(Function) with method references");
        ds.print(DataStructure::isEvenIndex);
        ds.print(DataStructure::isOddIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Java now uses Type Intereface i.e. it looks at what the expression returns and how the expression is used to determine it's type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ds.print` method takes an argument of type `Function<Integer,Boolean>`. So this:

```
ds.print(index -> {
    if (index % 2 == 0) return Boolean.TRUE;
    return Boolean.FALSE;
});
```

behaves equivalently to this syntax using an anonymous class instead of a lambda:

```
ds.print(new Function<Integer,Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(Integer index) {
        if (index % 2 == 0) return Boolean.TRUE;
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
});
```

(The functional method of the `Function` class is [`apply`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#apply-T-).)

So the parameter name `index` is arbitrary. You can call it whatever you want. It's just a name local to your lambda method. Its value is supplied by this call in `print`:

```
if (function.apply(i)) ...
```

Comment: I thought the compiler processes the lambda expression first before then going through the print function? How would it be able to get its value from function.apply(i) if this is the case, or am I missing something here?

Comment: @karsius It does process the lambda expression first, and turns it into a function object with a callable method. Each call `function.apply(i)` supplies the `i` value to `index` in the same way that calling any ordinary method supplies values to the parameters in the method.

Answer (score 0):

because the parameter of print is declared to be of type: Function from Integer to Boolean.